# How to save 2D arrays (lists) in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, save

I need to save a 2D array representing a map in the game world to a configparser. The data looks like this:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

As an example.

I can obviously save the data but I can't convert it from a string back to a list after reading it back in...

I don't mind if I have to use a .txt file instead, by the way, and just read it in with the normal text file handler.

Comment: [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) could also be a good way to get what you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python has a module for saving Python data called [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html). You can use that. From the docs:

> The pickle module implements a fundamental, but powerful algorithm for
> serializing and de-serializing a Python object structure. “Pickling”
> is the process whereby a Python object hierarchy is converted into a
> byte stream, and “unpickling” is the inverse operation, whereby a byte
> stream is converted back into an object hierarchy. Pickling (and
> unpickling) is alternatively known as “serialization”, “marshalling,”
> or “flattening”, however, to avoid confusion, the terms used here
> are “pickling” and “unpickling”.

Demo:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> data = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> with open('C:/temp/pickle_test.data', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(data, f)

    
>>> with open('C:/temp/pickle_test.data', 'rb') as f:
        new_data = pickle.load(f)

    
>>> new_data
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Sorry about the n00by sound of this following comment... I've only briefly heard of pickle and its purpose before... Basically, will this allow me to save the list and then read it back in as a list without any other hassle??? If so, then I'm thinking this is the way to go... Thanks for the speedy response!

Comment: I added a demonstration to my answer.

Comment: You need to open the file in binary mode `open('C:/temp/pickle_test.data', 'wb')` the same with read `open('C:/temp/pickle_test.data', 'rb')`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a simple eval

```
>>> x="[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]"
>>> type(x);
<type 'str'>
>>> y=eval(x);
>>> print(y);
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>>type(y);
<type 'list'>
```

It's a very quick and **dirty** solution, you should use more secure and good input files parsers (like pickle).

Answer (score -2):

For the transformation of a string to a list you could do something like this:

```
myList = [x for x in "0,1,2,3".split(",")]
type(myList)
<type 'list'>
print myList
['0', '1', '2', '3']
```