# How to save the content of 2D list to txt file in python3

Tags: python-3.x, list, save, txt

Here is the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996267/how-to-save-2d-arrays-lists-in-python). I'm curious how to only save the context wihtout bracket to txt. For example, a 2D list can contain int, float, and string.

```
L = [[0.23, 4, 'jon', 1], [0.333, 3, 'kit', 2]]
```

How to save to `file.txt` such that it will appear

```
0.23 4 jon 1
0.333 3 kit 2
```

wihout bracket `[]`, and there is a whitespace between two elements in one line.

Thanks.

Comment: How would you like strings that contain single quotes, commas or spaces to appear in the output?

Comment: @TurePålsson, update it. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it.

```
L = [[0.23, 4, 'jon', 1], [0.333, 3, 'kit', 2]]

with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:
    for row in L:
        file.write(' '.join([str(item) for item in row]))
        file.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1:

```
L = [[0.23, 4, 'jon', 1], [0.333, 3, 'kit', 2]]

F = open('file.txt', 'w')

for sublist in L:
    F.write(", ".join([str(element) for element in sublist]) + "\n")

F.close()
```

```
Output File.txt:
0.23, 4, jon, 1
0.333, 3, kit, 2
```

Solution 2:

```
L = [[0.23, 4, 'jon', 1], [0.333, 3, 'kit', 2]]

F = open('file.txt', 'w')

for sublist in L:
    F.write(str(sublist).replace('[', '').replace(']', '') + '\n')

F.close()
```

```
Output File.txt:
0.23, 4, 'jon', 1
0.333, 3, 'kit', 2
```