# Can I translate a file into a list in python?

Tags: python, list, file

I am making a 2D platformer game in Python, and I need to store the maps in a file, then load them as a list. The file will contain something like this:

```
[[1,1,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,1],
[0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0],
[2,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,2,2,2,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
[0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
```

and it needs to make a list like this:

```
platforms = [[1,1,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,1],
[0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0],
[2,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,2,2,2,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
[0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

**Is there any way I can do this?**

Comment: How about using a JSON file?

Comment: json seems like a good solution for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a list of numbers to jsonarray in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19795012/how-to-convert-a-list-of-numbers-to-jsonarray-in-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save 2D arrays (lists) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996267/how-to-save-2d-arrays-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) should handle that format:

```
import json  # At top of file

with open(filename) as f:
    platforms = json.load(f)
```

That trailing comma may be a problem; if so, you can either strip if off (if there's nothing else in the file, just doing `json.loads(f.read().rstrip("\r\n,"))` will remove any trailing newlines and commas before the parsing), or perhaps use `ast.literal_eval` instead (that will safely, unlike `eval`, interpret it as a one-`tuple` wrapping the `list`, which you can extract and verify the singular nature of with [the standard unpacking trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33161467/364696)):

```
import ast  # At top of file

with open(filename) as f:
    [platforms] = ast.literal_eval(f.read())  # Brackets to unpack the one-tuple
```